# How to install ubuntu-restricted-extras without ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: installation, restricted-formats

I want to install the restricted codecs to enable .mp3 playback and so on, in Totem, I attempted to install the metapackage, ubuntu-restricted-extras but it wants to install the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package.

I do not want to do this, the installer takes too long as it has to download the font archives and install them, I tried to use the ubuntu-restricted-addons package but it says I should not install it, I should install Ubuntu-restricted-extras instead.

Should I just find what packages are contained in the Restricted-extras and install those individually or is there a way to left something out of a metapackage during install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apt-cache show shows the following dependencies: gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse, ttf-mscorefonts-installer, unrar, gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse, libavcodec-extra-52, libmp4v2-0

Removing the ttf-mscorefonts-installer and adding the ubuntu-restricted-addons dependency we come up with this:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly-multiverse unrar gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse libavcodec-extra-52 libmp4v2-0 ubuntu-restricted-addons
```

However this doesn't solve your problem of the network download during the install. If you're doing a bunch of installations you might want to consider customizing the installer via [preseeding](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.10/installation-guide/amd64/preseed-using.html) or kickstart or something.

Comment: This is useful, I think it is the solution for now, I do not have a problem with downloading what I need, It was only the MS fonts installation that was holding things up, I do not care too much about these fonts being updated, so I have them already downloaded and extracted to install manually if I need them.